# Flutter Platform - ocd in platform order

Tags: flutter

Pardon the ocd, but how do you choose who to write first in the if?

```
// Is mobile
if (Platform.isAndroid || Platform.isIOS) {
    
}
```

‍♂️

Comment: use getx for  better platform detection https://dev-yakuza.posstree.com/en/flutter/getx/utils/

Answer (score 0):

In this case it doesn't matter. It's however you like it. But keep in mind that they are evaluated left to right, so it might matter in other cases like:

```
if (objectWithName == null || objectWithName.name == null) {
  
}
```

If you write it like this instead

```
if (objectWithName.name == null || objectWithName == null) {
  
}
```

then the program would crash when `objectWithName` is `null` because then it tries to access `objectWithName.name` on a `null` object. With the first example it doesn't even consider the second condition because the first condition is already true